# java.time.Period , dividing the period gives wrong results

Tags: java, time, period, localdate

I tried using `java.time.Period`, and the results were different from my manual calculations by three days.
The weird thing here is when I divide the period into two periods, the results matches my manual calculations.

The second method is just like how I calculate the period manually.

Is there something I have missed? Is there a standard method or algorithm of calendar arithmetic? And what's the algorithm used by `java.time.Period` ?

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.of(2014, 2, 14);
        LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.of(2017, 8, 1);

        Period p = Period.between(d1, d2);

        //using period between the two dates directly
        System.out.println("period between " + d1.toString() + " and " + d2.toString() + " is " + p.getYears()
                + " years " + p.getMonths() + " months " + p.getDays() + " Days");

        //dividing the period into two parts 
        p = Period.between(LocalDate.of(2014, 3, 1), d2);

        System.out
                .println("period between " + d1.toString() + " and " + d2.toString() + " is " + p.getYears() + " years "
                        + p.getMonths() + " months " + d1.until(LocalDate.of(2014, 3, 1), ChronoUnit.DAYS) + " Days");

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What results do you get? What results do you expect?

Answer (score 4):

You perform two different operations here:

```
Period p = Period.between(d1, d2)
```

gives you a nicely formated way to output the difference between these dates (you have used the formatting options correctly).

```
d1.until(d2, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
```

will give you the same - but not so nicely formated (basically it just gives you the number of days between the LocalDates).

Answer (score 1):

The answer (period between 2014-02-14 and 2017-08-01 is 3 years 5 months 18 Days) is what you should expect:

- it's 3 years from `2014-02-14` to `2017-02-14`
- it's 5 months from `2017-02-14` to `2017-07-14`
- it's 18 days from `2017-07-14` to `2017-08-01`

---

The calculation proceeds from years to months to days. This allows you to calculate the number of years, months and days between `2014-02-14` and `2016-02-29`, which gives 2 years and 15 days.

If you try to calculate the days first you have problems determining the number of years, months and days between `2014-02-14` and `2016-02-29`, because there is no day `2014-02-29` - 14 days after `2014-02-14` its `2014-02-28`, 15 days after `2014-02-14` its `2014-03-01`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot divide the period when computing days difference as you did, because period computation depends on the month/ year of the related dates. In your example,

The period between **14 Feb** and **1 March 2014** is just **15 days**,

while the **days** period between **14 Feb** and **1 Aug 2017** is computed from **14 Jul 2017** till **1 Aug 2017** which will be **18 days**, in details:

```
1) 14/02/2014 -> 14/02/2017: 3 years
2) 14/02/2017 -> 14/07/2017: 5 months
3) 14/07/2017 -> 01/08/2017: 18 days
```

This means that replacing **August 2017** by **March 2014** to compute the days difference independently from the whole dates will lead to an inaccurate answer (**15** while it should be **18 days**).

Therefore, you may have to consider the whole dates if you're doing any *manual computation* and not just its `day` section, or, just simply and safely use `Period` class given [methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) to perform your required dates computations.