# Calculation of Period between two LocalDate objects seems to be off

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate the difference between two LocalDate objects and the result seems to be off, but not every time.

I am using the Period construct. The below code shows one example which returns the expected result (I got that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45905720/3344703)) and another one which gives me the "wrong" result. I put that in quotes because I am not sure if that truly is wrong, or if the expected value is wrong. Note however, that if I use the online calculator from calculator.net, that gives me the result I expect.

```java
      public void manualTestPeriodBetween() {
        //works fine - expected result obtained
        LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2014, 2, 14);
        LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2017, 8, 1);
        Period result = Period.between(start, end);
        Period expected = Period.of(3, 5, 18);
        checkPeriods(expected, result);

        //does not work as expected
        start = LocalDate.of(2017, 5, 19);
        end = LocalDate.of(2019, 7, 13);
        result = Period.between(start, end);
        expected = Period.of(2, 1, 25);
        checkPeriods(expected, result);
      }
      private void checkPeriods(Period expected, Period result) {
        System.out.println("expected Period = " + expected + ", resulting Period = " + result);
        if (result.equals(expected)) {
          System.out.println("SUCCESS - result Period matches expected");
        } else {
          System.out.println("FAIL - result Period not matched");
        }
      }
```

Output:

```
expected Period = P3Y5M18D, resulting Period = P3Y5M18D
SUCCESS - result Period matches expected
expected Period = P2Y1M25D, resulting Period = P2Y1M24D
FAIL - result Period not matched
```

Can someone help me figure out whether I am missing something or the expected result is wrong (both in my code and the online date calculator)? or maybe something else I am not even considering.

Here is a screenshot of the results obtained from the online date calculator:

[image: Result from online date calculator]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The online date calculator you have provided **may have been implemented incorrectly**. From my favorite time resource, [timeanddate](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=5&d1=19&y1=2017&m2=7&d2=13&y2=2019)

> From and including: Friday, May 19, 2017
>
> To, but not including Saturday, July 13, 2019
>
> Result: 785 days
>
> It is 785 days from the start date to the end date, but not including the end date.
>
> Or 2 years, 1 month, 24 days excluding the end date.
>
> Or 25 month, 24 days excluding the end date.

This is identical to the response provided by [thecalculatorsite.com](https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/time/days-between-dates.php)

I don't have the implementation for your online calculator, but the discrepancy appears to occur because May is a 31-day month.

It looks to be calculating the day-difference before the month difference, using some mathematical assumption for month length.

The Java method uses `epochday` to calculate the distances between two days in case of underflow, rather than adding an arbitrary value to offset a month.

```
    if (totalMonths > 0 && days < 0) {
        totalMonths--;
        LocalDate calcDate = this.plusMonths(totalMonths);
        days = (int) (end.toEpochDay() - calcDate.toEpochDay());  // safe
    } else if (totalMonths < 0 && days > 0) {
        totalMonths++;
        days -= end.lengthOfMonth();
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean, it should be 24 days depending on how you do the calculations.

If you add a month to get to june 19th, and june has 30 days- then it's only 24 days between the two dates.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=days+between+5%2F19%2F2017+and+7%2F13%2F2019

[image: 2 Years 1 month 24 days]

The website you are checking it against is wrong, I can think of several ways that could happen depending on how they are implementing their date difference functions.